# OpenCV and include files

Tags: visual-c++, include, opencv, installation

has anyone installed OpenCV 2.0 on windows? Does the installation create directories such as "...\opencv\cxcore\include"? How do you link the libraries in Visual C++ 2008 (Express) and also the include files? In short how do you use OpenCV2.0 with VC++ 2008?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, documentation and examples on OpenCV2.0 are hard to come by. I would strongly recommend using OpenCV 1.1 unless there is a compelling need to use 2.0. There are [many](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B) [many](http://ai.stanford.edu/~dstavens/cs223b/stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf) more tutorials for installing OpenCV 1.x, than for 2 including those specific to Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for that - just installing the 1.1pre now - I suspected this and spent quit a lot of time trying to get it to work. Wasnt sure if anyone had done it. 1.

Comment: Yeah. Its a bit of a bummer too because I find all of the C++ object orientated-ness of the 2.0 version very appealing. However, if you are just getting started with OpenCV and you want to learn enough to quickly make code that works, I think 1.1 is the way to go. There is also a whole O'reilly book for 1.1 (not 2) at http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130  which I found very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Andy - just got the O'Reilly book - it is very well structured and mainly got it to save time rather than scounging the net. Will be keeping a keen eye on 2.0. 1.

Comment: Great! Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To includee OpenCV2.0 into VS2008, you will need to add path for both library and headers files into your project settings.

with your project opened, press alt+f7, then expand "configuration properties".
then goto C\C++ -> General -> "additional include directories", fill it up with path you get from opencv installation folder.

repeat the same process for library, which is under Linker -> General -> "additional library directories"